# handling device token in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The problem that i am having in my code is that when users login to their account, firebase saves the new device token without removing the former device token already stored in the database thereby assigning two different device token to one account so if i send a message to an account that has logged in with my device both of us get notified.

this is the code that gets device token in `LoginActivity`

```
 private void loginuser(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                        String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        String tokenID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                        mUserDatabase.child(current_user_id).child("device_token").setValue(tokenID).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                checkIfEmailsVerified();

                            }
```

Comment: Why don't you want the user to be able to use your app on two different devices?  Use of multiple devices is fairly common.  If you don't want to allow this, you're going to have to write your own code to deal with it.

Comment: but I don't think it's appropriate that a user should receive notification when he sends a message to another user

Comment: I think I do understand your problem. I faced it previously. Once you sent a message from one account to another, both get informed about the message. But it does not make sense, only the receiver should get informed, right?
Please provide us the code in where you send the messages and maybe a little screenshot of  the database node where the tokens are saved. It would help me to solve your problem.